# PHP Big File Handler Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, apache

I using angular file manager, to host some file on my server.
It's working well with small files, but when I want to download big files, I get Internal Server Error 500. File manager connect via ftp to get rthe files.
While I try download via FTP works well.
Apache error log is empty.
PHP error log is empty.

PHP.ini config

```
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
max_execution_time = 900000000
max_input_time = 900000000
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Idea?

Comment: probably run out of memory, or something.  You could register a shutdown handler and that would probably tell you.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: THX, I will try.